# Create a button with rounded border

Tags: flutter

How would you make a `FlatButton` into a button with a rounded border? I have the rounded border shape using `RoundedRectangleBorder` but somehow need to color the border.

```
new FlatButton(
  child: new Text("Button text),
  onPressed: null,
  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))
)
```

Example of how button with rounded button would look :  [image]

Answer (score 244, accepted):

Use [`OutlinedButton`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/OutlinedButton-class.html) instead of `FlatButton`.

```
OutlinedButton(
  onPressed: null,
  style: ButtonStyle(
    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
  ),
  child: const Text("Button text"),
);
```

Comment: Missed a closing quote after "Button text"

Comment: @RemiRousselet how can i change border color?

Comment: @Farhana in Flutter when `onPressed: null`, it means that the button is disabled, just do something with onPressed and the color will show.

Comment: `FlatButton` has the `shape` parameter as well and can have rounded corners just the same - no need to use OutlineButton.

Comment: @Hasen Well, using the same logic we can use `MaterialButton` for everything

Comment: @RémiRousselet, may I ask you to have a look at a Flutter related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60565658/fluter-image-picker-package-show-images-one-after-another-with-delete-action ?

Comment: @Farhana, to set the border color of an OulinedButton, use its property borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)

Comment: FlatButton, RaisedButton, and OutlineButton have been replaced by TextButton, ElevatedButton, and OutlinedButton respectively.

Comment: @egidiocs I can't find borderSide property. where to set this property?

Comment: with less typing, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70232237/4481235 suggests using `style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(shape, side)` then specify all available attributes if needed, which also works.

Comment: @Alexa289, 

`RoundedRectangleBorder(side: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xff004BCB)), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0))
`

Comment: style: ButtonStyle(
                                  side: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) => const BorderSide(color: AppColors.white),),
                                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),

Answer (score 88):

```
FlatButton(
          onPressed: null,
          child: Text('Button', style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.blue
            )
          ),
          textColor: MyColor.white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(side: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.blue,
            width: 1,
            style: BorderStyle.solid
          ), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
        )
```

Comment: FlatButton, RaisedButton, and OutlineButton have been replaced by TextButton, ElevatedButton, and OutlinedButton respectively.

Answer (score 58):

Use `StadiumBorder` shape

```
OutlineButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text("Follow"),
  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
  shape: StadiumBorder(),
),
```

Comment: For anyone who doesn't know, a StadiumBorder is a box with semi-circles on the end (like a track at a stadium, I guess)

Comment: You can try this also :shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),

Answer (score 23):

So I did mine with the full styling and border colors like this:

```
new OutlineButton(
    shape: StadiumBorder(),
    textColor: Colors.blue,
    child: Text('Button Text'),
    borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.blue, style: BorderStyle.solid, 
        width: 1),
    onPressed: () {},
)
```

Comment: Simple and elegant solution !

Answer (score 22):

```
new OutlineButton(  
 child: new Text("blue outline") ,
   borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
  ),

// this property adds outline border color
```

Comment: If anyone is wondering why the color doesn't appear, in my case it's because you need to pass a `onPress` not null.

Answer (score 4):

**For implementing the rounded border button with a border color use this**

```
OutlineButton(
                    child: new Text("Button Text"),borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                    onPressed: null,
                    shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0))
                ),
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `OutlineButton` and want to stick to normal `RaisedButton`, you can wrap your button in `ClipRRect` or `ClipOval` like:

```
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
  child: RaisedButton(
    child: Text("Button"),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
),
```