# How to change splash color of outlined button?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Latest outlined button doesn’t have any splash color property. How to change the splash color? Anyone have any idea

```
                  OutlinedButton(
                      style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                        onSurface: Colors.green,
                        side: BorderSide(color: alertColor, width: 1),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          FaIcon(
                            FontAwesomeIcons.trash,
                            size: 14,
                            color: alertColor,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 10,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Delete',
                            style: getFont(14, FontWeight.w500, alertColor),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay my mistakes. The `primary` properties in `OutlinedButton.styleFrom()` can change the splash color.

Comment: `primary` is deprecated use `foregroundColor` instead

Comment: It doesn't change splash color , it just changes the text color of the button

Answer (score 2):

You can change the splash color of the `OutlinedButton` by changing the  `style`

```
OutlinedButton.icon(
  onPressed: () {},
  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
  label: Label(
    text: 'Add',
  ),
  style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Colors.pink, // <- this changes the splash color
    side: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.pink),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: The `primary` property has been deprecated in favor of the `foregroundColor` property.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ButtonStyle` instead of `OutlinedButton.styleFrom`

```
style: ButtonStyle(
         overlayColor:
               MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>((states) {
                if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
                  return Colors.orange.withOpacity(.1);
               }
                return Colors.transparent;
       }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: Flutter 3.X with Material 3 support

```
IconButton(
  onPressed: (){},
  style: IconButton.styleFrom(
    highlightColor: Colors.red,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**overlayColor**

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle/overlayColor.html

> The highlight color that's typically used to indicate that the button
> is focused, hovered, or pressed.

```dart
OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
              side: BorderSide(color: alertColor),
              disabledForegroundColor: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.38),
            ).copyWith(overlayColor: Colors.red)
```